# Отправка простого POST запроса в Postman

Tags: c#, .net, post, postman

Подскажите, как отправить POST-запрос в Postman.
Я раньше не работал в этой сфере. Вот что я делаю:

- запускаю приложение в VS
- в Postman в строке запроса выбираю POST
- когда ввожу в строке https://localhost:5001/api/RemoveComplect, то выдает "404 Not Found"

Как мне отправить этот запрос? Вот сам метод

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveComplect([FromBody] CartComplectRequestVM complect)
{
    return Json(await _cartRepo.AddComplectAsync(CartId, complect, false));
}
```

В Body я выбрал JSON и написал:

```
{
    "promocode": "XCVBNM"
}
```

Comment: если вы не настраивали састомный роут, то в url должно использоваться имя контроллера, а не метода

Comment: Да, добавь название контроллера - https://localhost:5001/api/ControllerName/RemoveComplect